# An error occurs when submitting an improvement to a Suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I get this message each time I submit an improvement.

[image]

This has been happening since yesterday. Also, the next Suggested edit always fails to load afterwards.

I'm on a 3G network, so maybe a flaky connection? I also use Firefox 25 (haven't checked with anything else).

Comment: I see the same issue. Chrome over broadband, last day or so.

Comment: I would presume a flaky connection...

Comment: Nope, there's something going on SO-side, @Jan. Notice that there haven't been any successful edits (as opposed to approvals or rejections) to suggested edits in a long time.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta okay then, upvoting...